# Can't resolve compiler.es5.ts

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4.2.4. I can build the apllication in my machine but it keeps failing in another one (TeamCity),

```
Cannot find source file 'compiler.es5.ts' Can't resolve './compiler.es5.ts' in 'F:\Autobuild\Tools\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\3dedcccb1ddec6c9\src\ui\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular'
```

Comment: For me this path looks strange `\node_modules\@angular\compiler\@angular`, try deleting the `\node_modules\@angular` folder and do `npm install` again.